# VID/PID for Virtual HID

Tags: virtual, hid

I'm developing a driver for a virtual HID that I'm working on. I am wondering, what values should I / can I pick as my Vendor ID and Product ID. Obviously I don't want to cause conflicts with existing VIDs and PIDs. What are my options, any tips?